# Regular expression for positive numbers from 1-99 up to 1 decimal places PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for accepting positive numbers from 1-99 and accepting decimals up to 1 places. This is for entering input for blood glucose level readings.(In PHP).

Examples:

```
1.9, 10, 10.5 - Pass

0.9, 10.135, 103, 103.5, 103.13 - Fail
```

Comment: Is regex only option? I think solution could be much easier if you treat input string (or it's parts) as numbers?

Comment: JQuery is (a library of) JavaScript, that works client-side in the browser. PHP works server side, before the client receives the page, or with information received from the client. Which do you want help with? What efforts have you made, where did they go wrong (and how)?

Comment: Must `99.9` pass or fail?

Answer (score 0):

The following php code will help you in the checking .

```
<?php

$subject = "10.19"; // desired number 
$pattern = '/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])(?:\.[1-9])?$/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $subject))
echo 'true';

?>
```

Comment: @nevermind i thought what he wanted was 1-100 ( excluding 100 ) .

Answer (score 0):

You can us a regex like this:

```
^[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d)?$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH6yD3/1)**

[image]

Php code:

```
$re = "/^[1-9]\\d?(?:\\.\\d)?$/m"; 
$str = "Pass\n1.9\n10\n10.5\n\nFail\n0.9\n10.135\n103\n103.5\n103.1\n\n"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```